# Is it OK to uninstall old versions of Win10 and .NetCore SDKs?

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-sdk

[image]

I have a development VM that's taking a lot of disk space. I am trying remove unused apps/tools. I just found out that I am keeping these old versions of Win10 and .NetCore SDKs. I'd like to know if it is ok to remove the old versions and keep the latest? I'm worried if it might encounter problems compiling my old projects. I would really appreciate your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sure you'll encounter problems rebuilding old projects.  Fairly likely that you'll have to change their SDK or .NETCore target.  How much of a pita that might be for your users is impossible to guess, you can't get a warranty here when you tell us so little about it.  If it matters then a build server with a terabyte disk is always a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your response @HansPassant. I removed all those old versions and luckily I did not encountered any problem compiling my .net core 2.1 projects.